# How do I enter < and > on a broken keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mojave

As per title: I've a broken keyboard where the <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> keys don't work anymore. Can I insert such symbols with a <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>  combination?

I would prefer to avoid direct ASCII code numbers, if possible.

Comment: On your keyboard, are those also the , and . keys?

Comment: And do you have a mouse, in order to do a one-time configuration of settings or tool?

Comment: @shoover I suspect the OP may be using one of the European language keyboards where <> are on the key just right of left shift.

Comment: If you know how to use AppleScript or Automator, try using them to press the key combinations then create a shortcut? If not, Keyboard Maestro should be able to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

macOS doesn't do 'alt-codes', that's a Windows feature.*

Simplest solution might be to use the Keyboard Viewer, accessible from the Menu Bar once enabled in: System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard

On a UK keyboard they're accessed by pressing  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>

[image]

**From comments:*
They can be made to work, though I feel they're more effort than really needed ;)
System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources > Plus sign > Unicode Hex input. After you choose it, you can do `Option` then `003C`, it'll show the `<` symbol.

Comment: Alt codes do exist. System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources > Plus sign > Unicode Hex input. After you choose it, you can do `Option` then `003C`, it'll show the `<` symbol.

Comment: Ugh, yes - I'd forgotten about that, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You can remap those characters to the <kbd>option</kbd> keys using [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele).

You could also set up keyboard shortcuts for them via: System Preferences > Keyboard > Text > Replace  With